# How to set the context path in Spring Boot WebMvcTest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to test my Rest controllers from my Spring Boot application and want the controllers to be available under the same path as in production.

For example I have the following Controller:

```java
@RestController
@Transactional
public class MyController {

    private final MyRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MyController(MyRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/myentity/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Resource<MyEntity>> getMyEntity(
            @PathVariable(value = "id") Long id) {
        MyEntity entity = repository.findOne(id);

        if (entity == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return new ResponseEntity<>(entity, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Within my `application.yml` I have configured the context path for the application:

```
server:
  contextPath: /testctx
```

My test for this controller looks as follows:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = MyController.class, secure=false)
public class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyRepository repositoryMock;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Test
    public void testGet() throws Exception {
        MyEntity entity = new MyEntity();
        entity.setId(10L);
        when(repositoryMock.findOne(10L)).thenReturn(entity);

        MockHttpServletResponse response = this.mvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/testctx/myentity/10"))
            .andReturn().getResponse();
        assertEquals(response.getStatus(), 200);
    }

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {
        @Bean
        MyRepository mockRepo() {
            return mock(MyRepository.class);
        }
    }
}
```

This test fails since the status code is 404 for the call. If I call `/myentity/10` it works. Unfortunately the rest call is initiated by a CDC-Test-Framework (pact) so I cannot change the requested path (containing the context path `/testctx`). So is there a way to tell spring boot test to start the rest endpoint with a defined context path also during testing?

Comment: They are the same, however you are wring a UNIT test not an INTEGRATION test. You are testing the controller in isolation so it doesn't do anything with the servlet path. If you want that you have to make it a proper integration test instead. But what is wrong with having `/myentity/10` in your test and have your other test suite call the actual application...

Comment: I feared that there is no chance to to this while unit testing...
The above code is only an example. In my real test the Pact framework hooks in and performs the request. Within the test I have no chance to intercept the call from Pact to get rid of the context path. Since I want a fast unit test instead of a slow integration test I was looking for a way to set the context path even for the mocked controller.
I now updated the Pact framework and remove the context path before sending the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = {MyController.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
class MyControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Value("${server.servlet.context-path}")
    private String contextPath;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        assertThat(contextPath).isNotBlank();
        ((MockServletContext) mockMvc.getDispatcherServlet().getServletContext()).setContextPath(contextPath);
    }
    
    protected MockHttpServletRequestBuilder createGetRequest(String request) {
        return get(contextPath + request).contextPath(contextPath)...
    }
```