# Can I configure the Spring Cloud Contract Pact test generation to handle a context in the URL path

Tags: spring, rest-assured, pact, spring-cloud-contract

I have a demo project here https://github.com/donalthurley/pact-demo which shows the problem I'm having.

The general problem is that I am trying to develop an API that complies to a PACT contract where the contract is using a URL path that includes a context.

The spring boot controller API maps the request without the context in the path see
https://github.com/donalthurley/pact-demo/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/DemoController.java#L22

The PACT contract specifies the same request with the context 'demo' prepended to the URL path see 
https://github.com/donalthurley/pact-demo/blob/master/src/main/resources/demo-pact.json#L14

When pact generates the unit tests it fails in this case with a 404.

If the context is removed from the PACT contract then the generated tests succeed.

My question is this, is there any way I can tell the PACT generation to use the 'demo' context so that the generated tests will work?

This earlier answer [How to set the context path in Spring Boot WebMvcTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39469237/how-to-set-the-context-path-in-spring-boot-webmvctest) would suggest that this is not possible but I would like to confirm that as I don't understand why this shouldn't be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my humble opinion, you shouldn't include the context in the pact, the same way like your controller does.
I guess you are using some API-gateway, So all dealing with the context should be ended once you leave the API-gateway. In your service level the context is already irrelevant.

Comment: I'd agree with that. I think the PACT contract should not use the context.
I thought that maybe the RestAssuredMockMvc might allow you to set a context which would support integration testing which Spring allows you to do on controllers.
But I think probably the best option for me here is to ask the PACT contract writers to exclude the context.